# Using feature vectors from imagenet to train xgboost (vs a standard Conv net)?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, xgboost

I am planning to use feature vectors generated from imagenet to train an xgboost model. This is as opposed to training a standard convolutional network with the same image set.

This is because we use xgboost internally across several of our modeling tasks and is just a matter of personal preference. Has anyone noticed any issues - deterioration of accuracy or performance? Anything we should be looking out for?